# Android WebView loses AppBar

Tags: android, webview, appbar

I am loading a WebView in my application.  I have enabled an AppBar and it displays while waiting for the WebView to load.  Once the page has loaded, it looks like it opens a new activity and replaces my AppBar with its own.  In this case I would be happy with a proper up button returning to the parent activity.  (I would like the back button to work as well as the up button)  As it stands, the back button takes me back to the xml layout here which I don't understand how I left.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.realpayment.app.activities.ReadMessage"
android:background="@color/c_black">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/JupiterTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"/>
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calledAction"
    android:layout_margin="15px"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:textColor="@color/c_white"
    />
```

And I am initializing my appbar in onCreate with

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I am loading the webpage with

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.calledAction);
browser.loadUrl(sCallToActionLink);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using linear layout**

Using layout weight attribute so webview covers as much space is left by toolbar and also override **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method to make sure that page navigation should be in your WebView

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.realpayment.app.activities.ReadMessage"
android:background="@color/c_black">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/JupiterTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"/>
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/calledAction"
    android:textColor="@color/c_white"
    />
```

Comment: Good idea, but it seems to be starting a new activity, so this didn't work.  I am trying to keep it on that screen, almost like a frame

Comment: you are loading url in webview how a new activity is launched i didn't understand

Comment: I agree, I don't understand either.  What happens is that I see the screen that is described in the layout (with a blank for the WebView) and then it animates a full screen browser.  At that point if I hit the back button it goes back to the blank layout.  That feels like it is a new activity, but I honestly don't know what it is doing.

Comment: I put an answer in - it was redirecting the link and that was causing the new browser activity.

Comment: @DanielleCox also did you override **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method

Comment: I did not - I will look at that now!

Comment: make that your answer and I will checkmark it!  That is exactly it.  Since I was seeing a slightly different problem, I asked a different question, but now I think it is a duplicate and this will be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was because I was browsing to "http://" and it was redirecting to "https://" which was causing the issues.  Fixing the link and the view behaved as it should have.